# c# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

From package manager console in visual studio 2022 whenever I am running below migration command

Add-Migration AddtableCampaign

following error ocurrs

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.GetPendingMigrations(IEnumerable`1 localMigrations)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInternal(String name, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String migrationsConfigurationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.Scaffold.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
```

I am running simple entity framework migration command but cannot find the problem for this solution

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Can you show us what changes you have made that you are expecting to be included in the new migration?

Comment: @phuzi this error is occurring even i am running empty migration without expecting any changes